# jQuery & asp.net - index rows with classes client-side

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In ASP.NET gridviews we can create a template and insert a named (id) control.  This way we can iterate rows after a POST.  But, is there a way to index rows with say, classes so that we can group rows together via index?

This way I can use jquery to pull a row with a particular quality, like say

```
"row1CheckBox == checked"
therefore gather all columns with class = rowIndex1.
```

I'm a little hesitant to use code behind with ASP.NET to name the classes because it has a tendency to put class names on `<span>` instead of the templated object, e.g. the `<textbox>` within the `<span>`.

I hope this question is clear.  Has anyone done this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(".row1CheckBox :checked") should return all classes with the Checked attributed.  I don't think that's what you're looking to do though.  Perhaps some clarification?

[Checked Selector Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Comment: Well, this is what I am currently using. Yes it does work. I'm looking for something more generic.  Also, something that won't break if say there are 2 grids on the page with checkboxes.  I want to index the rows on client-side in the same fashion I can iterate the rows on server-side.  It should be possible by marking each row on DataBind event with a class name that identifies the index (row1Class, row2Class, row3Class...), but I.m not sure how to implement it successfully.

Comment: Well, if you're just wanting *any* input field you could do `$("input :checked")` and pickup all input fields that are checked, but it would pick up radio buttons too (I think).  But you'd manually have to sort between grids (if relevant).

Comment: It may just be that the ASP.NET webforms controls do not lend themselves to such behavior (because the `<span>` issue I mentioned).  This would almost certainly be much more do-able if I just had a table with some C# helpers, like MVC-3 stuff.  Then I could directly mark the class names instead of depending on ASP.NET's controls.

Comment: Actually you can reference the DOM parent in jQuery, see http://api.jquery.com/parent/ for details.  It should allow you to reach from the span and then verify the checked status.

Comment: Thats a very interesting idea.  In this case I think it would be a children that I need, but yes you are right.  That will work.